# SSRS Reports design for Manual Execution and Data Driven Subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, subscription

I have created a report that users are able to run on demand. I have the data source set to prompt for authentication.

The business also requires that we send this report out as a data driven subscription. With a data driven subscription, all data sources have to have Credentials stored securely in the report server.

Because of the business requirements of allowing users to manually execute the report when they want and to have the report sent out as a data driven subscription, I have 2 versions of the same report and have to update them both when changes are needed.

Is there a way to have 1 report that users can manually execute (being prompted for credentials) and it also be sent out as a data driven subscription?

Comment: Use a service account on the database to run your report. Then setup Active Directory groups for folder access. Is there a reason you need to identify the user running the report? e.g. row level security

Comment: Because we use row level security, we force the users to authenticate before they can run the report.

Comment: If you want to both use data driven subscriptions and row level security, you'll have to pass the user id to the dataset/view/stored procedure. Then you can run the report using a service account.

Comment: First of all, let me thank you for even responding. I truly appreciate it. Let me ask a question. With a data driven subscription, you have to have your data source configured with a service account and password. Wouldn't that mean that when a user runs the report, it wouldn't worry about who they were since the data source is configured with the credentials? To me it sounds like it would be defaulting to the service account and not the user manually kicking off the report.

Comment: Yes, the report would run under the service account, but you can pass the user id by using the built in function `User!UserID`. Then you can apply the row level security in the view/stored procedure.

Comment: When you run under the data driven subscription the you would need to pass the email you're sending to the view/stored procedure as a parameter to do the row level security.

Comment: If you post an example of the source, I'll post how I'd set it up